# Can someone help me find the segfault here?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, trie

EDIT: So, it turns out that 'index' was not being returned to 0. Well then. That fixed one segfault. But still getting a different segfault. Working on it.

```
node* new_node(void){
    node* ptr = malloc(sizeof(node));
    for (int i = 0; i<27; i++) {
        ptr->next[i] = NULL;
    }
    return ptr;
}
bool load(const char* dictionary)
{
    FILE* dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    node* ptr = new_node;
    char word[LENGTH+1];
    int index = 0;
    for (int c = fgetc(dict); c!=EOF; c = fgetc(dict)){
        if(c!='\n'){
            word[index]=c;
            index++;
        }
        else {
            for(int x=0; x<=index; x++){
                int ch = (word[x] == '\'') ? 26 : tolower(word[x])-'a';
                if (ptr->next[ch] == NULL){
                    ptr->next[ch] = new_node;
                }
                ptr = ptr->next[ch];
            }
            ptr->end=true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm trying to implement a trie data structure for a dictionary but my program seems to segfault somewhere in this function. I can't seem to pin it down even with the help of GDB, so can someone give me a hand?

Node is defined as such:

```
typedef struct node{
    bool end;
    struct node* next[27];
} node;
```

Dictionary file:

```
a
aaa
aaas
aachen
aalborg
aalesund
aardvark
aardvark's
aardvarks
aardwolf
```

(...)

Comment: Also, always check that malloc returned properly...

Comment: @Haris why is this? shouldn't the memory allocated be the size of the node object?

Comment: @Haris I thought if I typedef as such: typedef struct node{
    bool end;
    struct node* next[27];
} node; then I should be able to allocate memory of size node to a node*?

Comment: @Haris yes should have included it in OP, it was in a separate file (dictionary.h)

Comment: @Haris It doesn't seem correct to allocate a pointer at all. Why would he do that for? And what do you mean with "Exactly, and the node object ptr is of type node * and not node". malloc returns a pointer to the allocated object... so your point is...?

Comment: @MOehm, Yes. I see. :)

Comment: One problem in the code is that the 27 child node pointers are not explicitly initialised to null after allocating them.

Comment: @MOehm since *ptr is junk when first created, doesn't the first allocation have to be sizeof(node)? then this line:  ptr->next[ch] = malloc(sizeof(node)); could become sizeof(*ptr) instead.

Comment: @MOehm doesnt my first for loop initialize them to null?

Comment: `for (char c = fgetc(dict); c!=EOF; c = fgetc(dict))` should be `for (int c = fgetc(dict); c!=EOF; c = fgetc(dict))`. You cannot portably compare a `char` with `EOF` because the `EOF` value might not be representable by a `char` value.

Comment: `struct node* next[27];` Eeeh? Why is this variable called next? I thought this was some sort of linked list? What's "next" supposed to be, some sort of look-up table? Is this a chained linked list? Hash table?

Comment: It's a trie, so each node has pointers to 27 other arrays (one for each letter of the alphabet and an apostrophe) as well as a switch that tells you whether a word ends here

Comment: @IanAbbot thanks will update to reflect

Comment: The `sizeof` operator doesn't look at the contents of `*ptr`, only its type. Of course, seeing `*ptr` when `ptr` hasn't been initialised should make you suspicious, but it is safe to run `sizeof(*ptr)`, which will give you `sizeof(node)` regardless of its contents.

Comment: @murtaza64: Your first loopinitialises only  the root node's children to `NULL`. Every time you allocate new memory, you create a new uninitialised object. Perhaps it is better to write a constructor function `node_new` that allocates and initialises the node.

Comment: Also: What happens to the trie? You don't return it; it just goes out of scope at the end of the function.

Comment: @MOehm check the OP please--is this correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107751/discussion-between-murtaza64-and-m-oehm).

Comment: LENGTH has been defined as 45 (longest word in dict)

Comment: When the debugger fails you and the brain is foggy, do the crude and old-school thing of putting printf's in your code, e.g., make sure you're not overrunning your arrays (are you sure index is always <27?), sanity check values of everything - easily done and might surprise you.

Comment: @CarlH the debugger hasn't failed him. He just doesnt know how to use it.

Comment: One more issue: the reading of one work is wrong, the resulting string in the `word` array is not zero terminated.

Comment: @murtaza64 please: next time you ask a question on stackoverflow include directly all relevant information in the question. There have been too many comments asking your for information you should have included into your question from start. [Read also this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @UmNyobe - Yes, most likely, hence the foggy brain caveat!  Point is still valid, though - sometimes something as silly as a printf is simpler and faster than the more obvious and conventional methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have many issues in your code:

- When you allocate memory with `malloc`, it is uninitialised. initialise it directly after allocating it, so that `NULL` pointers really are null. (`calloc`, a cousin of ´malloc´, initialises all memory to zero.)
- When you loop over the word, you should nor include `index`:

  ```
  for (int x = 0; x < index; x++) ...
  ```
- When you have found the end of a word, you must reset the `index` to 0. Otherwise, you will append to the old word and overflow the buffer. (You should probably also enforce the upper bound of ´index´.)
- Likewise, when you insert a word into the trie, you must reset your pointer for trie traversal to the trie's root. You need two pointers here: A root node pointer and an auxiliary pointer for traversing the trie.
- As is, your trie is local to your function. Return the root node, so that other functions can use the trie, or `NULL` on failure.

Fix these, and you will have a non-crashing function. (It still leaks memory and may not construct the trie properly.)

```
    node *load(const char *dictionary)
    {
        FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
        node *head = calloc(1, sizeof(node));

        char word[LENGTH + 1];
        int index = 0;

        for (int c = fgetc(dict); c != EOF; c = fgetc(dict)) {
            if (c != '\n') {
                word[index] = c;
                index++;
            } else {
                node *ptr = head;

                for (int x = 0; x < index; x++) {
                    int ch = (word[x] == '\'') ? 26 : tolower(word[x]) - 'a';
                    if (ptr->next[ch] == NULL) {
                        ptr->next[ch] = calloc(1, sizeof(node));
                    }
                    ptr = ptr->next[ch];
                }
                ptr->end = true;
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        return head;
    }
```

Comment: Good. As I said: The segfault and memory errors are gone, but I haven't checked whether the code works properly.

Comment: I finished the problem and managed to get the entire spellchecker working only 0.01 second slower than the cs50 staff's example. Now to shave that off too.

Comment: Good! But 0.01 seconds may well be a measuring inaccuracy. And focus on correctness first: A fast program that produces wrong results isn't worth much. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
node* ptr = new_node;
```

and

```
ptr->next[ch] = new_node;
```

are not calling the function, but assigning the address of the function to `ptr`. Call the function instead.

This problem could have been prevented if compiler warnings: `-Wall` and `-Wextra` were enabled.

---

There is no bounds checking done on the array `word`. Use the value `LENGTH` to check if the index is in bounds before using it.

It isn't clear what the if statement inside the for loop is doing. It appears that every time a newline is found the whole array `word` is added to the tree, but the `index` isn't reset so the same array is added multiple times. At some point `index` will point out of bounds causing undefined behavior. You should reset `index` after you use the array `word`.

Comment: Thanks, this was an issue, but the segfault was occurring even before I implemented this function

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to reset `index` to `0` at the beginning of the loop.

You should also use `calloc(1, sizeof(node))` instead of `malloc(sizeof(node))` to avoid leaving memory uninitialized. I suggest you use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to help you track problems of this kind in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You should filter punctuation\unsupported characters a bit more. Any character outside of `[a-z|A-Z|\n|\\]` will crash your program because of

```
int ch = (word[x] == '\'') ? 26 : tolower(word[x])-'a';
if (ptr->next[ch] == NULL){
```

Given that you open a file, there might be a space somewhere or some unexpected character. You need something like

```
    if(c!='\n'){
        int num = (c == '\'') ? 26 : tolower(c)-'a');
        if(num >=0 && num < 27)
        {
           word[index]=c;
           index++;
        }
    }
```